# How do I remove divider image from menu

Tags: css

I created a menu with divider image. so every list item looks separate from each other. but the problem is I couldn't figure out how to remove the last divider. I tried with li:last-child {background:none}, but it is not working. here is the code I'm using at this moment:

```
.top-menu {
    background: url(../images/bg_linkstop.jpg) repeat-x;
    border: #FFF 2px solid; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    height: 52px;  
    list-style: none;

    li {
        float: left;
        height:48px;
        padding: 0 22px;
    background : url(../images/bg_divisor.png) no-repeat center right;

        }       
}
```

& here is the result:

[image]

You can see it is not looking good, as last menu item has a divider to its right side. I want to remove that divider image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following rule **after** your css:

```
.top-menu li:last-child {
    background :none;
}
```

Make sure to place this **after** the css code you provided. no reason this shouldn't work. (if you believe you have conflict try adding `!important`)

This will remove the background only for the last matched `li`.

Comment: Dude, I tried it before. but didn't work. this time working though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look into `:last-of-type` selector, it think it is self explaining. Although this selector don't work for IE8 an earlier

You can find more information for this selector [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
 li {
    float: left;
    height:48px;
    padding: 0 22px;
     background : url(../images/bg_divisor.png) no-repeat center left;
 }
```

Change bg position from right to left, so that you can target the first item (see below)

First child is IE8 supported

```
li:first-child {
  background: none;
}
```